# Default Version of Appengine App (from code)

Tags: google-app-engine

How to find out the default version of appengine app?
I don't mean the current version, but rather the  version which serves the requests by default.

PS. Sorry if the question was not clear enough. I meant, how to find the default version from code. I have a number of versions of the app, and I need to find out programmatically which one is default.

Comment: The question is valid one, although might not mean much to people not well aware of appengine platform. If not clear better ask, rather than marking it not clear. The purpose here is to promote the share of knowledge, not make it difficult.

Comment: There is nothing at all wrong with the question.  You people just aren't familiar with Appengine.  Stackoverflow should have a system to vote down inappropriate moderator actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manually:

- sign into https://appengine.google.com
- choose your application
- select "versions"
- see if there is a "yes" in the default column

Programatically:

```
import com.google.appengine.api.labs.servers.ServersService;
import com.google.appengine.api.labs.servers.ServersServiceFactory;

...

ServersService ssf = ServersServiceFactory.getServersService();
String defaultVersion=ssf.getDefaultVersion(ssf.getCurrentServer());
```

Comment: thanks for reply. But I was looking for a programmatic way of doing it.

Comment: @husayt Please see the revised answer.  It is possible now.

Comment: Have you got it running on server? I get this error when deployed: com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException: The API package 'servers' or call 'GetDefaultVersion()' was not found.

Comment: Yes I get that same error when deployed.  It should work per the api so I think it is a bug.  I noted that at https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1996

Answer (score 1):

Since last version of Appengine  with intro of module API, they have added a new way to get default version.

```
import com.google.appengine.api.modules.ModulesService;
import com.google.appengine.api.modules.ModulesServiceFactory;

....

ModulesService ssf = ModulesServiceFactory.getModulesService();
DEFAULT_LANDMAX_VERSION = ssf.getDefaultVersion(ssf.getCurrentModule());
```